# WordPress css problem - borders not showing up

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

I'm working on page in Word press. The theme buttons aren't what i was looking for so i decided to make a custom ones. I thought it would be simple:

`<button type="button" class="btn menu-button">BUY</button>`

and css:

```
.btn{
    font-size: large;
    background: transparent;
    border: solid;
}
```

So here is where my problem occur.
Some of the css code is working just fine (font-size for example) but the borders won't show up no matter what. I thought that the problem lies in the button tag itself but after futher investigations i noticed that it happens for every html element on my page, no matter div, p, H - the border stylization is not working neither color choice nor size, style etc.

So please help me, how can i make not only some but every css line work.

Im using WP 5.5.3  with customify theme. I've put The css from above into the custom css tab.

Comment: maybe you have `border: none` somewhere in your theme that overrides your own css? Did you check it?

Comment: In your browser's dev tools look at the styling that is actually being used by a button and you should be able to see where in the CSS the border is being unset. It could for example be the theme using !important but may be something else.

Comment: border: none was the problem, thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Borders usually require the `border-style` in order to have any of the other border styling properties to work. Try replacing with:

```
border-style:solid;
```

Alternatively, you can add them all to one line allowing you to omit the `border-style` by adding something along the lines of:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```